# How to use csv data to support dependent drop down in Angular

Tags: angular

Consider there are 3 drop down by Angular,

```
Name  |   Address |  Social-SSN
```

in the back end there is a csv file with same structure, each row represent dependent options for each job down.

for example

```
"Mary", "123 Fairyland", "123-45-6789"
```

Whenever user choose "Mary" from drop down `name`, or "123 Fairyland" from dropdown `Address`  or or "123-45-6789" from dropdown `Social-SSN` , the value for the other two columns should automatically pop up based on the corresponding row value in the csv.

This post is not lazy guy asking for exact implementation, but look for guidance of the solution. I am not Angular Guru so don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the data allways has the same index, you can use that to set the selected index on the other dropdowns.

Here is a very basic angular app with html `select` to get u started:
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pwzpae?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks much ! May I ask how to bind selected index without `ngModel`? because I need to use `ngModel` for the entity to save

Comment: I have updated the the stackblitz, how you can use the setter to set the other values.